# JQuery Поиск по тексту

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть некоторое кол-во элементов в котором нужно найти все фразы начинающиеся с `#`

Для примера, вот сам html код:

```
<div id="gallery">
 <span class="portfolio-desc">Текст для примера #test_test1 #test2</span>
 <span class="portfolio-desc">Текст для примера #test2</span>
 <span class="portfolio-desc">Текст для примера #test_test1 #test_test5 #test2</span>
</div>
```

Нужно найти все фразы начинающиеся с `#` без повторений. Т.е. вывести скрипт должен такой массив:

```
('#test_test1', '#test2', '$test_test5')
```

Пробовал подобным образом сделать, но не смог разобраться в регулярках:

```
var elementText = [];
var a;
$('#gallery span').each(function(i, selected){
if($(selected).text().match('#(.*)')){
  elementText.push($(selected).text().match('#(.*)'));
}
});
a=elementText.join();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данным способом:

```
function unique(arr) {
  var result = [];

  nextInput:
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var str = arr[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
        if (result[j] == str) continue nextInput;
      }
      result.push(str);
    }

  return result;
}
var elementText = [];
var a;
var rege = /#[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z_0-9]+/ig;
$('#gallery span').each(function(i, selected){
if($(selected).text().match('#(.*)')){
  elementText.push($(selected).text().match(rege));
}
});
a=elementText.join();
```